# Getting the top level permalink using get_post_ancestors()

Tags: permalinks, sub-menu

I have a function for displaying **the title** of the top-level page of the current sub-level page. It's working quite well, but I can't figure out how to also link to the same top level page that is displayed.

```
function my_page_ancestor() {
    global $post;
    if( !is_front_page() ) {
        $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post );
        $top_parent_link = get_permalink( end($parents) );
        echo '<a href="' . $top_parent_link . '"><span class="pageAncestor">' . get_the_title( end($parents) ) . '</span></a>';
    }
}
```

I've tried `get_the_permalink()` inside the function, but it just breaks.

**Edit:**
I've corrected the function above, and it now works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink) ie: `get_permalink( end($parents) )`. :-)

Comment: Oh that's embarrassing :-) Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: Indeed, that's a mean one. :-)